# Different behavior of java.lang.system.exit(status) on windows and linux

Tags: java, linux, centos

I have a usecase where I need to perform op on parent process based on the exit code of child process.

Therefore in child process, I am using :

```
java.lang.System.exit(1641);
```

while in parent process, I am doing:

```
Process process = processBuilder.start();
int retCode = process.waitFor();
// do something based on this retCode
```

On windows, this works as expected. But on CentOS, I am getting 105 as return code instead of 1641.

What am I missing here?

Comment: You are getting the lower 8 bits. See: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/418784/what-is-the-min-and-max-values-of-exit-codes-in-linux

Comment: @ImperishableNight Thanks. This was indeed the case. Any value less than 127 works for me. You can add this an answer if you would like to.

Comment: `System.exit` returns an `int` according to Javadocs; see [Class System | exit(int)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#exit(int)). `waitFor` also returns an `int`. Why is the return code being truncated?